# Using gpio-admin errors: no such file or directory

Tags: gpio

I'm trying to make a NodeJS app control gpio on my new Pi 2, I'm using the pi-gpio node module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio) and followed the instructions to the letter, not only logging out but even rebooting.

However, whenever I try to use gpio-admin I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/projects/gpio-test $ gpio-admin export 22
gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of 
/sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio22/direction: No such file or directory
```

When trying to use the pi-gpio module in my app I get an error

```
Error when trying to open pin 7
gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of
/sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio4/direction: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does the file exist? if so who is the owner and waht are the permissions? you can get this by doing ls -la /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio22/ or ls -la /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio4/

Comment: Haven't we had the same question before?  At the time I suggested a check to see if gpio-admin needs updating for the Pi 2.  That goes for any module which accesses the gpios directly.

Comment: **In case the duplicate is not clear**, it's because `gpio-admin` is outdated; the correct path is `/sys/class/gpio`.  It has been that way for a while -- certainly long before the pi 2 -- although that may depend on how recent a kernel you run.  This is not something that is restricted to Arch either, it is that way on Raspbian.